# Is opencv image similarity comparison reliable for objects? Is there any cost/benefit quality alternative to open-source API's?

Tags: image, opencv, comparison

I'm trying to choose an API to match object images taken with a cell phone with a list of images in a file system. The point is, I'm afraid that I won't get reliable results and it won't be worth it to loose time in this feature.
I would really appreciate some advice regarding this topic.

Comment: You should decide to yourself, why are you doing this (feature). Only you can decide is it worth to you to spend time on it at all or how much time are you ready to spend. Then you have to quantify the word "reliable". No API is perfect, so you have to compare them by providing the same series of input image pairs to each API and counting how many correct answers you have.

Comment: That's my approach, however I need to purchase some of them in order to try them.

Comment: Look for evaluation period/trial with API providers.